# How deal with rude and hateful attitude of the younger sibling when you are to advice them in a good context?

Tags: teen, siblings

When you have not much success in your career or studies and try to save your younger sibling from the bad company or anything that can ruin his life, then he starts hating you. How to deal with this behavior wisely?

Comment: How old are you and your sibling? Did they _ask_ you for help or are you their primary care giver?

Comment: My brother is 7 year younger than me,  my parent also take care of him but when I try to tell my parents about his activities he start hating me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't relevant to the parenting stack. Try inter-personal relations?

Comment: I think this is too broad, and not really within the remit of Parenting. I'm not sure it is in a useful state for IPS, but worth a look over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced the same with my child and hopefully, I was successful to teach him a lesson and drove him back on a track. I think, If you don't have any club it ok! buy having a bad company it totally disaster. only with the help of "Love" you can deal with the rude and hateful attitude 1) Discover the root of the problem 2) maintain your parental status 3) discuss a solution 4) don’t condem. I hope you will be successful too!